# Styling stack divs in UL

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, meteor-blaze

I have been trying to style 8 divs stack in rows and columns but could not. I want to place icons in these divs. Though I think having a picture of what exactly I want would be better so I attached a screenshot.

[image: style divs]

This is the code:

```
<template name="User">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <li class="user black {{selected}} results" id="user-link" style="font-family: 'candara'">
            <span class="name" style="color: black; font-family: 'candara'"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: red;"></i> {{newschoolnamevar}}</span>
            {{#if selected}}
                <hr>
                <div class="jokeInfo">
                    <div>
                        <span class="possy blue" style="color: black;">Motto: {{newschoolmottovar}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <span class="author" style="color: black;"> Author: {{author}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <span class="author" style="color: black;">Vision: {{newschholvisionvar}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <span class="author" style="color: black;">Mobile: {{mobile}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <span class="author" style="color: black;">Sell School: {{sellschoolvar}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: have you tried flex-box?

Comment: No. Any idea is welcome

Comment: your html is invalid li cannot be a child of a div

Answer (score 1):

Identify the container's LI and give this:

```
 ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
 }
```

and the LI:

```
li {
 width: 25%;
}
```